# Twitch API get historical viewers count of game

Tags: python, json, twitch

I am using Twitch api with python to get the total number of viewers for a specific game such as Dota 2.
The following code gets the **current** viewer count for a game:

```
import requests


def main():

    header = {"Client-ID": "477xu1lvl2jiqzk9s0e3vc8rgip9os"}

    search_game_url = 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?query=dota&type=suggest'
    search_game = requests.get(search_game_url, headers = header)
    search_game_total = search_game.json()['games'][0]
    print("Name: " + str(search_game_total['name']) + ", Popularity: " + str(search_game_total['popularity']))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

What I need to do is to get the total history of viewers count. In example, I want to get the viewer count of a game, for every week for the past five year. Can anyone help me with that ??

Thank youu so so much !!

Comment: There is nothing in the API that provides this information currently.  There do appear to be some third-party sites that have collected this kind of information, but I'm not sure if there is any kind of API available.  https://sullygnome.com/games https://socialblade.com/twitch/

Answer (score 1):

If you print the entire dictionary you get this

```
{
   "_links":{
      "self":"https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/games?query=dota&type=suggest"
   },
   "games":[
      {
         "localized_name":"Dota 2",
         "box":{
            "template":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Dota%202-{width}x{height}.jpg",
            "large":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Dota%202-272x380.jpg",
            "small":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Dota%202-52x72.jpg",
            "medium":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-boxart/Dota%202-136x190.jpg"
         },
         "locale":"",
         "name":"Dota 2",
         "logo":{
            "template":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Dota%202-{width}x{height}.jpg",
            "large":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Dota%202-240x144.jpg",
            "small":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Dota%202-60x36.jpg",
            "medium":"https://static-cdn.jtvnw.net/ttv-logoart/Dota%202-120x72.jpg"
         },
         "_links":{

         },
         "_id":29595,
         "popularity":35436,
         "giantbomb_id":32887
      }
   ]
}
```

I don't see a value for the entire history of views for dota inside of here. However, if you can find that data elsewhere, just grab that total and divide by number of weeks in 5 years. Not sure where you can find that though.